# How do I retrieve the row with the max value from this table?

Tags: sql

Hopefully this is the correct place to ask this question. In this [SQL cross-join exercise from codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-sql/lessons/multiple-tables/exercises/cross-join) with the following code:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM newspaper
CROSS JOIN months
  WHERE (start_month<=month) & (end_month>=month)
GROUP BY month;
```

Returns a table

| month | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 5 | 27 |
| 6 | 30 |
| 7 | 20 |
| 8 | 22 |
| 9 | 21 |
| 10 | 19 |
| 11 | 15 |
| 12 | 10 |

How can I then retrieve the row with the max COUNT(*) from this table?
{month:6, COUNT( * ):30}?

I tried the following which doesn't work (returns blank on the website):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM newspaper
    CROSS JOIN months
      WHERE (start_month<=month) & (end_month>=month)
    GROUP BY month)
WHERE COUNT(*)=(
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM
   (SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM newspaper
    CROSS JOIN months
      WHERE (start_month<=month) & (end_month>=month)
    GROUP BY month)
    );
```

Preferably, I would to this to work without renaming COUNT(*).

P.S: No idea which SQL dialect codeacademy uses.

Comment: I'd use `AND` instead of `&`.

Comment: Good questions will explicitly say what "doesn't work" means, even if it's obvious to some.

Comment: You need to tag your question with the SQL dialect handling this query. Otherwise, anyone who attempts to answer might guess incorrectly or be forced to answer for all dialects that have a unique way to get the first row of a "top query".

Comment: Didn't take long to find [this](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-sql/lessons/manipulation/exercises/sql). "what database does codeacademy use" Looks like sqlite.

Comment: @Jeff Holt: Cool, thanks.

Comment: Since you accepted an answer that uses TOP, then it's not SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized we don't need a CTE to do this, you can simply do:

```
SELECT TOP(1) month, COUNT(*) FROM newspaper
CROSS JOIN months
  WHERE (start_month<=month) & (end_month>=month)
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY 2 DESC
;
```

This will grab the top row, and it will be ordered by the highest count. I am unsure of language used by CodeAcademy, but every language I know of can grab the top row in some fashion.

Edit:

I see someone posted that CodeAcademy uses SQLite, which uses `Limit` to get X amount of rows. So you can use:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM newspaper
CROSS JOIN months
  WHERE (start_month<=month) & (end_month>=month)
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```